# cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &

Tags: c++

Hi so i have two Problems:

1. `cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &`

   ```
   void CMapObjectPropertyPageAmbience::OnUpdateUI(CProperty* pProperty)
   {
       prt::PropertyAmbienceStringToData(pProperty, &m_propertyAmbience);

       std::vector<CFilename>& rSoundFileNameVector = m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector;
       for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < rSoundFileNameVector.size(); ++dwIndex)
       {
           m_ctrlSoundFileList.InsertString(dwIndex, rSoundFileNameVector[dwIndex].c_str());
       }

       m_ctrlPlayType.SelectString(-1, m_propertyAmbience.strPlayType.c_str());

       SetDialogFloatText(GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_MAP_OBJECT_PROPERTY_AMBIENCE_INTERVAL, m_propertyAmbience.fPlayInterval);
       SetDialogFloatText(GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_MAP_OBJECT_PROPERTY_AMBIENCE_INTERVAL_VARIATION, m_propertyAmbience.fPlayIntervalVariation);
       SetDialogFloatText(GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_MAP_OBJECT_PROPERTY_AMBIENCE_MAX_VOLUME_AREA_PERCENTAGE, m_propertyAmbience.fMaxVolumeAreaPercentage * 100.0f);

       OnUpdatePropertyData(m_propertyAmbience.strName.c_str());
       OnChangePlayType();
   }
   ```

   The Error appears at:

   ```
   std::vector<CFilename>& rSoundFileNameVector = m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector;
   ```
2. None of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types:

   ```
   void CMapObjectPropertyPageAmbience::OnDeleteSoundFile()
   {
       DWORD dwCurSel = DWORD(m_ctrlSoundFileList.GetCurSel());
       if (dwCurSel >= m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector.size())
           return;

       DeleteVectorItem < CFilename > ( & m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector, dwCurSel);
       m_ctrlSoundFileList.DeleteString(dwCurSel);
   }
   ```

   at `DeleteVectorItem<CFilename>(&m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector, dwCurSel);`

Full Errors

```
1>Dialog\MapObjectPropertyPageAmbience.cpp(78): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CFilename
1>          ]
1>Dialog\MapObjectPropertyPageAmbience.cpp(205): error C2665: 'DeleteVectorItem' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          d:\dev\kraizy\novaline\srcs\client\eterpack\../eterBase/Stl.h(146): could be 'void DeleteVectorItem<CFilename>(std::vector<_Ty> *,unsigned long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CFilename
1>          ]
1>          d:\dev\kraizy\novaline\srcs\client\eterpack\../eterBase/Stl.h(191): or       'void DeleteVectorItem<CFilename>(std::vector<_Ty> *,T)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CFilename,
1>              T=CFilename
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::vector<_Ty> *, DWORD)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
```

Comment: What type is `m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector`? Show the exact and complete text of the error messaged - it will tell you what types the compiler thinks `_Ty` stands for, and what functions the compiler considered and rejected when looking for a suitable overload.

Comment: There are usually follow-up lines that explain what `_Ty` is. Look at the Output window.

Comment: &m_propertyAmbience.AmbienceSoundVector that is taking address of this vector, remove &

Comment: That looks horrible in the comments. Can you add it to your question with `<pre>`...`</pre>`?

Comment: Please add the errors as an edit to the original question and remove those comments afterwards. This will increase the readibilty greatly!

Comment: So, you are trying to bind a variable of one type, `vector<string>`, to a reference to another, completely unrelated type, `vector<CFilename>&`. Why do you expect this to work, and are surprised when it doesn't?

Comment: i edited the errors in..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `vector<string>` in places where `vector<CFilename>` is expected. Those are completely unrelated types.